# setUTCHours Adds an hour to time passed to the function

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, datetime, utc

I am trying to create a DateTime object from date and time strings separately.
However setUTCHour function keeps on adding an hour to the time, I understand UK's time is GMT + 1 However as the time is already stored in UTC Time I don't want to add an hour to the time..

below is the code for this..

```
var eventStartDate = $('#EventStartDate').val();  // value:  "10/10/2016"
var eventStartTime = $('#EventStartTime').val();  // value:   "10:00"
var eventStartTimeArr = eventStartTime.split(":"); 

if (eventStartTimeArr.length = 2) {
    eventStart.setUTCHours(eventStartTimeArr[0], eventStartTimeArr[1], 00, 00)
}
```

This shows me event start time as "10/10/2016 11:00" which is one hour more then exprected value.. this should be "10/10/2016 10:00".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`setUTCHours`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setUTCHours) is basically [`setHours`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setHours) using the UTC offset.

For example, if you were in the GMT-7 timezone, using `setUTCHours(10, 0, 0, 0)` would be equivalent to using `setHours(10 + (-7 /* local time offset */), 0, 0, 0)`.

If you have already set your time in UTC, you don't need to re-apply that offset (as the object's local time is now UTC time). Use [`setHours`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setHours) to directly apply the hours instead.

Comment: what is the ideal solution.. our Application is in development phases and w e are targeting international audience.. should we be worried about how we are saving our date time..
we deal with events, so if some one in US is to see when these events are happening then they should be able to see these in their local time not uk time.

Comment: Dates should be stored in your database as UTC and retrieved as UTC. They can be converted to/from the local timezone in the browser via Javascript. This allows for consistent data across multiple time zones.